# How to set a file input control to save uploaded pdf files with application/pdf instead of application/octet-stream to firebase in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, firebase-storage

I have a form to upload pdf files to firebase I have also set the file input control to `accept=" application/pdf "` but it always saves the file with `application/octet-stream` and can't view it. could anyone please help me with any suggestion out there?

Here is my form:

```
  <form [formGroup]="formTemplate" (submit)="onSubmit(formTemplate.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4>Please choose a file for upload</h4>
      <input type="file" class="form-control"
             accept="application/vnd.cups-pdf, application/pdf "
             formControlName="selectedFile"
           (change)="previewFile($event)">
      <p>Please choose a file to upload <span class="text-warning">(pdfs, 
      docs, or ppts)</span> </p>
      <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="isSubmitted && 
       formControls.selectedFile.errors?.required">
        A file is required</div>
    </div>
```

Here is UploadComponent.ts:

```
previewFile(event:any){
if(event.target.files && event.target.files[0]){
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e:any) => this.imSrc = e.target.result;
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  this.selectedImage = event.target.files[0];
 // console.log(this.selectedImage.name)
  this.fileName = this.selectedImage.name;
 // console.log(this.fileName);
}
else
  this.imSrc = this.defaultImage;
 this.selectedImage = null;
```

};

```
  onSubmit(formValue) {
this.isSubmitted = true;
if(this.formTemplate.valid){
  var filePath = `${formValue.category}/${this.fileName.split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.')}_${new Date().getTime()}`;
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
  this.storage.upload(filePath, this.selectedImage)
    .snapshotChanges().pipe(finalize(() =>{
      fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) =>{
        formValue['selectedFile'] = url;
        this.service.saveResourceDetails(formValue);
        this.resetForm();
      })
  })).subscribe();
}
```

}

Comment: Please add code snippet which you have tried

Comment: @VRK I have just added the code please take a look :-)